# converting textFile to dataFrame dynamically

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert input from a text file to dataframe using a schema file which is read at run time.
My input text file looks like this:

```
John,23
Charles,34
```

The schema file looks like this:

```
name:string
age:integer
```

This is what I tried:

```
object DynamicSchema {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val inputFile = args(0)
    val schemaFile = args(1)
    val schemaLines = Source.fromFile(schemaFile, "UTF-8").getLines().map(_.split(":")).map(l => l(0) -> l(1)).toMap
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("Dynamic Schema")
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val input = spark.sparkContext.textFile(args(0))
    val schema = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(schemaLines)
    val nameToType = {
      Seq(IntegerType,StringType)
        .map(t => t.typeName -> t).toMap
    }
    println(nameToType)
    val fields = schema.value
      .map(field => StructField(field._1, nameToType(field._2), nullable = true)).toSeq
    val schemaStruct = StructType(fields)
    val rowRDD = input
      .map(_.split(","))
      .map(attributes => Row.fromSeq(attributes))
    val peopleDF = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schemaStruct)
    peopleDF.printSchema()

    // Creates a temporary view using the DataFrame
    peopleDF.createOrReplaceTempView("people")

    // SQL can be run over a temporary view created using DataFrames
    val results = spark.sql("SELECT name FROM people")
    results.show()
  }
}
```

Though the printSchema gives the desired result, result.show errors out. I think the age field actually needs to be converted using toInt. Is there a way to achieve the same when the schema is only available at runtime?

Comment: please post the error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
val input = spark.sparkContext.textFile(args(0))
```

with

```
val input = spark.read.schema(schemaStruct).csv(args(0))
```

and move it after schema definition.

Comment: Thanks!! Worked like charm. Just a related question. Is the way I am building the StructFields and StructType correct way of doing it? Or is there a better or more elegant solution?

Comment: `broadcast` doesn't make sense. The rest looks reasonable.